# Simple D3 line chart example

Tags: d3.js

I'm a D3 newbie and having a slow time getting up to speed on this library.  I am trying to get this simple D3 area chart to work but am having some trouble displaying the actual area it self.  I can get the axis to display correctly with the right ranges for the data, but no area displays on the graph itself.

I am feeding it JSON data that looks like this and it appears to be consuming the data fine as best as I can tell.

```
[{"Date":"Date","Close":"Close"},{"Date":"20130125","Close":"75.03"},{"Date":"20130124","Close":"75.32"},{"Date":"20130123","Close":"74.29"},{"Date":"20130122","Close":"74.16"},{"Date":"20130118","Close":"75.04"},{"Date":"20130117","Close":"75.26"},{"Date":"20130116","Close":"74.34"},{"Date":"20130115","Close":"76.94"},{"Date":"20130114","Close":"76.55"}]
```

This is my code

```
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var area = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.Date); })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.Close); });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.json('JSONstockPriceOverTime.php', function (data) {
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
        d.Close = +d.Close;
      });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Close; })]);

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");
    });
```

And I have this style applied

```
        <style>

        body {
          font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #000;
          shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .area {
          fill: steelblue;
        }


    </style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the starting part of the json (JSONstockPriceOverTime.php) file;

`{"Date":"Date","Close":"Close"},`

Since it has the 'Date' and 'Close' variables defined as part of the json format, you won't be required to include header information like a csv file, and add 'error' into your json load line

`d3.json("JSONstockPriceOverTime.php", function(error, data) {`

and you should be all go (worked for me).

You're making good progress.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with it all. Depending what level you're at you might be interested in the [D3 Tips and Tricks](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks) manual (you may as well, it's free!) or other similar code examples at d3noob.org.